# Can an JS generated Image HTML element throw an exception?

Tags: javascript, exception

I've found this code from Facebook where there is a try catch which I don't understand.

fb_param is a JS object where the only required property is pixel_id, but that requirement is checked by an if clause.

Can anyone tell me how this code can throw an exception?

```
/*1375267557,179355677,JIT Construction: v893363,en_US*/

/**
 * Copyright Facebook Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 */
try {
  (function() {
    if (typeof fb_param != 'undefined' && fb_param.pixel_id) {
      var a = 'https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php',
        b = a + '?id=' + fb_param.pixel_id;
      if (fb_param.value) b += '&value=' + encodeURIComponent(fb_param.value);
      if (fb_param.currency) b += '&currency=' + encodeURIComponent(fb_param.currency);
      var c = new Image();
      c.src = b;
    }
  })();
} catch (e) {
  new Image().src = "http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/" + 'common/scribe_endpoint.php?c=jssdk_error&m=' + encodeURIComponent('{"error":"LOAD", "extra": {"name":"' + e.name + '","line":"' + (e.lineNumber || e.line) + '","script":"' + (e.fileName || e.sourceURL || e.script) + '","stack":"' + (e.stackTrace || e.stack) + '","message":"' + e.message + '"}}');
}
```

Comment: I think it's for this `(function() {})();`, not for the code inside that function.

Comment: And do you happen to know how that code could also fail with an exception?